# yarn create app with a specific version of a app

Tags: node.js, hadoop-yarn, strapi

Is there a way to use the following:

```
yarn create strapi-app my-project --quickstart
```

but use a specific version of strapi like version v4.13.6 instead of the latest which at the time of writing is v4.13.7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`@` symbol is everything you need. The convention of using a package of a concrete version is usually `package@1.0.0`.

So for npx it will look like this

```bash
npx create-strapi-app@4.13.6 my-project
```

but I think `yarn create` may be an exception, look at [this issue](https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/6587). Bear in mind that `yarn create` is a command that `creates new projects from any create-* starter kits` so I guess for now they do not support a concrete version usage for the command (that may be reasonable assumption that user will always want to start a new project with the latest version).

My advice to you is just use `npx` for now.

Comment: I woudl use the `npx create-strapi-app@4.13.6 my-project` like shared by Moti.